# Resharper says "Cannot resolve view"

Tags: model-view-controller, view, resharper

It is already 9.2 version released. This problem still is not fixed since 8 version. Please help if someone knows what to do.

Answer (score 0):

Create an issue with details at https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issues/RSRP

Comment: ViewComponent is a new feature of ASP.NET 5.0 which is in beta currently. It will be supported in next version of ReSharper (still before ASP.NET 5.0 will be released). is it your case?